# Convert int and concatenate it with char*

Tags: c++, g++

I want to convert an `int` to `char` or `char*` then concatenate it with a `char*`

```
for (int i = 1; i < mymap.size(); i++)
{
    char * s = "Scene";
    cout << mymap[s+i];
}
```

I tried this way

```
string s = "Scene";
string x = to_string(i);
s = s + x;
char* si = s.c_str();
```

But I get an error.

But this works:

```
const char* si = s.c_str();
```

But then I try to use it with `mymap`:

```
cout << mymap[si];
```

and I get an error says i must use `char*` and not `const char*`

Comment: Could you provide us with the complete error you receive so that we may further debug your issue?

Comment: What is the type of `mymap` ? Why do you want to cast your key into `char*`and do not keep it as a `std::string` ?

Comment: is `mymap` a `std::map`? Make the key a `std::string`, not a `char*`, and your code will work.

Comment: @Dave: either a `std::string` or a `const char*`...

Comment: Try `cout << mymap["Scene" + to_string(i)];` if `mymap` is keyed with `string`, `cout << mymap[("Scene" + to_string(i)).c_str()];` if it's keyed with `const char*`, and if it's keyed with `char*` then change it to `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a little excessive, but you could try a stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
 char * a = "hello";
 int b = 11;

 stringstream sstm;

 sstm << a << b;

 string ans = sstm.str();
 char * ans2 = (char *) ans.c_str();

 cout << ans2 << endl;   //"hello11"

 return 0;

}
```